# HttpListener and IntegratedWindowsAuthentication across network

Tags: windows-authentication, httplistener

I've created a ClickOnce service using HttpListener.  I need to authenticate the user's connection:

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:80/ClickOnce/");
listener.AuthenticationSChemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
while (true)
{
    var context = listener.GetContext();
    var id = context.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
    if (id != null)
    {
        using (var impersonated = id.Impersonate())
        {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine as long as the service is on the same machine as the Http client.  But if I try to connect to the service from another machine, it refuses to authenticate.

If I connect through Internet Explorer, it prompts for username/password, attempts to connect, and then goes back to the prompt.

If I connect through Chrome, it just says "This webpage is not available ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS".

If I run VSTOInstaller.exe, it gives the following error:

```
 System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException: Downloading http://.../OutlookAddin.vsto did not succeed.
 System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
 System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The target principal name is incorrect
    at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatus& statusCode)
 ...
```

If I configure anonymous authentication, it allows the requests through, but then I can't authenticate the users.

Can HttpListener authenticate over a network?  Or is there another alternative to HttpListener which supports this scenario properly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is too late, but based on your error description it can be (is) an issue with Kerberos authentication.

More specifically it is either missing SPN records or mismatch in request header. Check what was actually sent in Fiddler and verify that SPN matches record. I would also suspect specified port in you prefixes. This error frequently happens if you have non standard port in url.

Comment: It is rather late, I ported the whole thing to IIS because that was the only way I could get it to actually authenticate properly.